# want to have a button in my preferences (android)

Tags: android

I have a seperate preference xml called prefs.xml, here is its code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <Preference 
        android:key="clear"
        android:summary="Press if you want to clear your data"
        android:title="Clear Data?" />
     <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="tut"
        android:summary="Check if you want to see the tutorial when the app starts"
        android:title="Tutorial Show/Hide" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

EDIT: I thought that preference thing was going to be the button but i dont really know what it does or how to use it

what i am trying to do is be able to press a button or something that when its pressed, do something else, i dont know where to put the code or what i should do, my prefs.java file's code is here:

```
package com.mittereder.rockpaper;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class prefs extends PreferenceActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
    }

}
```

if that helps at all

Comment: Can you just define a button on your main xml file? Then set an onClick listener and do something when you click the button. Not sure if I understood the question correctly.

Comment: what you need exactly, a screen with a button and when you press it an other screen appear for example

Comment: @ABDOU is there anything in the preference screen that i can use to click something to execute code?

Comment: @0gravity in my preference screen i want to be able to press something that will execute code to reset values, but i am using a preference screen and i don't know if there is anything i can add to execute code like a button, i tried adding <Button /> but just crashed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
public class prefs extends PreferenceActivity implements OnPreferenceClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs

        findPreference("clear").setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference p) {

     //your code here 

             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "je suis la " + p.getTitle(),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }

}
```